# Who recorded Rusty Dusty Blues for the first time?

Tags: recording, blues

The song *Rusty Dusty Blues* has been sung by many blues musicians. For example, BB King has recorded this song. I also have Jimmy Rushing (with Count Basie Orchestra) version from 1943, I believe. I want to ask if this is the first orchestra/singer to record this song, or has anyone before Count Basie recorded it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Louis Jordan also recorded it in 1946 ( http://www.discogs.com/Louis-Jordan-And-His-Tympany-Five-Louis-Jordan-And-His-Tympany-Five/release/4552135 ), but to the best of my knowledge, the Count Basie recording is the original.